# NuGet - Package dll is NOT copied to output directory

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a .NET 5 class library project. This project is dependent on a NuGet package. My code will not compile without this NuGet package. However, once I have added this package, my code successfully compiles. However, I've noticed that the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory does not have a .dll for the NuGet package like I expect. The other NuGet packages that I'm referencing have .dll files in the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory like I expect. My problem is, when I use this library in my runner, it fails to run because it's looking for the .dll associated with the NuGet package, but it's not there.

Why would the .dll for a NuGet package *not* get copied to the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory? I can see that the NuGet package has a .dll file in it's `[version]/lib/netstandard2.0` directory. I need that .dll in my `bin/debug/net5.0` directory. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I believe I've isolated the issue. To isolate the issue, I did the following:

1. Created a new .NET 5 console app. Added the LiteDB NuGet package. Added a reference to the `LiteDB` namespace. When compiled, the LiteDB.dll is in the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory as expected.
2. Created a new .NET class library project. Added the LiteDB NuGet package. Added a reference to the `LiteDB` namespace. When compiled, the LiteDB.dll assembly is *not* in the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory as expected.

The console app .csproj includes `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`. The class library project does *not* include an `OutputType` element. This is the only difference. However, since the `OutputType` [defaults to library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019), this makes sense. However, the question is, how do I get the LiteDB.dll assembly to appear in the `bin/debug/net5.0` directory for a class library project. That's what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by "my runner"?

Comment: @JonSkeet The runner is an open source project (nopCommerce) that relies on plugins. My class library is a plugin (which is a class library).

Comment: There are many Nuget packages out there, which one should we use when trying to reproduce this?

Comment: @RoarS. I'm using a LiteDB which is very popular.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] that would make it easy to reproduce...

Comment: Having just tried this with NodaTime as a dependency of an otherwise-empty class library, I've found that using `dotnet publish` makes everything available in bin/Debug/net5.0/publish - would that be enough for you? (Fundamentally, the way the .NET Core-and-onwards build system works just doesn't require all DLLs to be copied all the time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately, publishing doesn't work as it doesn't include _any_ of the .dlls, which, the runner requires. Thank you for sharing though.

Comment: That's surprising - and emphasizes the need for a [mcve], given that your experience is different to mine when I *attempted* to reproduce this.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've isolated the issue. In addition, I've added reproduction steps above.

Comment: Your options are to publish or to set the CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies property in your project file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copylocallockfileassemblies.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - you said that publishing didn't include the DLLs - whereas it's working fine for me. I'm publishing by running "dotnet publish" - how are you doing it, and have you tried using "dotnet publish"? (Note that they end up in a subdirectory - bin/Debug/net5.0/publish.)

Comment: I had this problem with Google.Protobuf.dll nuget package, @outstacked 's tip of adding CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies to the project file worked for that.